# convert game from portrait mode to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to `cocos2d` game developing. Here,  my game is developed in portrait mode. I just want to convert landscape mode. and tell me which method is used instead of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method because this method is not available in iOS 6?

My whole game is developed portrait mode from the start.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you mean in landscape as well or only landscape?

Comment: in which cocos2d version are you working 1.x or 2.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will solve your problem, but as you mentioned How to handle orientation in OS6, I would like to give you the code what I am using for Handling Device Orientation in iOS 6 and iO5 etc.

So here is the code snip, where you can decide what orientation support you want in your app

**Handle Screen Orientations in iOS 5 and iOS 6**

```
//For up-to iOS 5.0
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported all orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


//For iOS 6.0
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Supporting only portrait orientation.
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2012/05/iphone-tips-and-tricks.html)

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 3):

you will find below code in appdelegate.mm file

```
 #if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
 #else
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

change it to.

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
 #else
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to target and set supported interface orientation.